# Issue with multiple threads in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm trying to realize a stress test in a Camel project that receives a key to decrypt some query parameters. However, when I add multiple *vusers*, the sequence of threads seems to lose the order.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

The thread 7 enter in the middle of the sequence of thread 4, is there anyway to control this? In these cases where the sequence is broken, I can't decrypt data cause in the thread I have other key to open.

I'm using direct: in my route, I've tried to use seda with no concurrentConsumers and the process become to slow, utilizando concurrentConsumers parameter the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using SEDA component and multiple consumers, apparently this component controls the various consumers and only starts consumption when the previous consumer is finished.

My route:

```
from("seda:route?multipleConsumers=true")
                .to("toRoute")
```